# How to get HTML code in <iframe> with "srcdoc" attribute by selenium Java?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, java

I need to access the page elements that are in the iframe with the src Doc attribute and I'm not getting the full content.

Page code:

[image]

Java code with WebDriver:

[image]

This is turns out to get:

[image]

But I need all page code, can i do this with webDriver ?